# Nested routes inside react component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-component

I'am searching for this but i couldn't find a proper answer. Is it possible to use React Router like this inside React Component;

```
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router'    
import LandingLayout from '../../layouts/landing/LandingLayout'
import AppLayout from '../../layouts/app/AppLayout'

<Switch>
  <LandingLayout>
    <Route path="/" exact="true" component={Home} />
    <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
    <Route path='/signup' component={Signup} />
  </LandingLayout>
  <AppLayout>
    <Route path='/dashboard' component={DashboardPage} />
    <Route path='/users' component={UserList} />
    <Route path='/u/:username' component={AccountPage} />
  </AppLayout>
  <Route component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: First of all, at "/dashboard" or "/users" route the page comes with Landing Layout, it must render App Layout and content section in the middle empty. But at "/" home or login page it renders correctly.

Comment: Also server.js logs this. 

Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `exact` of type `string` supplied to `Route`, expected `boolean`.
    in Route
    in Routes
    in Router
    in StaticRouter
    in Provider
    in LocaleProvider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of research i got the right answer for my case.

First of all my React application is a server rendered app. 
Second; i am using React Router Switch because of performance related issues.

Above solution not worked for me because of my app architecture and i got some errors like;

> You should not use Route component and Route children in the same route; Route children will be ignored

So here; i want to use React Router Switch with multiple layouts. And here is how to do it.

First you will create a custom Router component which combines the Layout and Component. Say "AppRouter"

```
const AppRouter = ({ component: Component, layout: Layout, ...rest }) => (
   <Route {...rest} render={props => (
     <Layout>
       <Component {...props} />
     </Layout>
   )} />
)
```

Second; for public and private routes there must be two different layout wrapper

```
const LandingRouteLayout = props => (
  <div>
    <LandingLayout {...props}/>
  </div>
)

const AppRouteLayout = props => (
 <div>
   <AppLayout {...props}/>
 </div>
)
```

Last; Routes

```
const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <AppRoute exact path="/" layout={LandingRouteLayout} component={Home} />
      <AppRoute path="/login" layout={LandingRouteLayout} component={Login} />
      <AppRoute path="/signup" layout={LandingRouteLayout} component={Signup} />
      <AppRoute path="/t/:token" layout={AppRouteLayout} component={SetToken} />
      <AppRoute path='/dashboard' layout={AppRouteLayout} component={DashboardPage} />
      <AppRoute path="/u/:username" layout={AppRouteLayout} component={AccountPage} />
      <Route component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Switch only works with Route and since you render LandingLayout and AppLayout without Route, both of them will be rendered defaultly and while its ok to add the Routes as Child Routes, its better if you add them inside the component and since you want to have the LandingLayout and AppLayout render separately you would have to write them as routes

```
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router'    
import LandingLayout from '../../layouts/landing/LandingLayout'
import AppLayout from '../../layouts/app/AppLayout'

<Switch>
  <Route path="/landing" component={LandingLayout}/> 
  <Route path="/app" component={AppLayout} />
  <Route component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

**LandingLayout**

```
render() {
   return (
       <div>
          {/* other things*/}
          <Route path={this.props.match.path} exact="true" component={Home} />
          <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/login`} component={Login} />
          <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/signup`} component={Signup} />
       </div>
   )
}
```

**AppLayout**

```
render() {
   return (
       <div>
          {/* other things*/}
          <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/dashboard`} exact="true" component={DashboardPage} />
          <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/users`} component={Login} />
          <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/u/:username`} component={AccountPage} />
       </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: Do note that `this.props.match.url` is recommended for `Link`s. Sometimes people use `this.props.match.path` for both `Route` and `Link`

Comment: Thank you for alternatives but this is not the appropriate solution. I can not use routes like "/landing/home" or "/landing/login".

Comment: Routes must be like these; 

“/“ 
“/login” 
“/signup”
“/dashboard”
“/users“

And so on..

Comment: Basically i want to use 2 master layouts (views). One for landing page, the other one for app. How can i achieve this.